# excel offset function returns value error

Tags: return-value, excel-formula, offset

I am having an issue with the offset formula in Excel and I cannot understand what the issue is. I have used the formula before with success. The formula is

```
=OFFSET($B$3,,,,COUNTA($B$3:$T$3))
```

It is supposed to be reading a horizontal list of dates. This will become a named range and used in a chart. Cell B3 contains the first date and the width is the counta function. Would the cell format - date in this case - have any impact on the formula?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the formula itself I can't see a problem. If you enter this (say in A3) as is, it will display the value of B3 because OFFSET returns a **range** and a single cell operation on a range results in displaying the value of its first cell.

If B3:T3 is completely empty the COUNTA resolves to "0" and hence the OFFSET resolves to #REF.

A typical application of the OFFSET function would be something like =SUM(OFFSET(...)) where the SUM acts on the complete range provided by OFFSET

Comment: Hi Mike, I would be happy if it returned the value of B3 but as it is, it returns #Value and I can't see a reason. I am using COUNTA so that I can add new dates to the range and have the chart update automatically

Comment: try the =COUNTA() on its own to see what this returns, and try the =OFFSET() with a constant (range 0 .. 19) in place of COUNTA() to see what this returns ...